# Htaccess lowercase URL substring if found it in different case

Tags: .htaccess

I want to lowercase part of the URL string in .htaccess if it is not lowercase already.

Example,

`http://www.example.com/This-Needs-to-Change/cars.aspx`

to

`http://www.example.com/this-needs-to-change/cars.aspx`

What should be my Rewrite condition to change only if uppercase letter is found for that string (this-needs-to-change) only?

Comment: hi @anubhava yes i have it, but would prefer to do it in .htaccess if possible to avoid apache restart and modify later as per need

Comment: ok I can do that then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define this `RewriteMap` in your httpd config file or in vhost config file:

```
RewriteMap lc int:tolower
```

Then in your site root .htaccess have this rule to lowercase first part before `/`:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond $1 [A-Z]
RewriteRule ^(this-needs-to-change)(/.*)?$ /${lc:$1}$2 [R=302,NC,NE,L]
```

Comment: cars.aspx could be anything dynamic. Will this affect any other uppercase strings in URL as we allow some of them?

Comment: to be more clear, I only want to modify exact one string (this-needs-to-change) and all the other strings should not be affected.